# How to remove whole Site Actions menu for specific users?

Tags: sharepoint

I have been doing research, and I havent found a way to remove the WHOLE site actions menu for "non-content editors" in sharepoint.  I have researched this:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageSubwebs">
```

but this only hides certain links in the site actions menu, what if I want to hide the whole thing so you cant even see 'site actions' in the upper left hand corner of the page for certain users.  The content editors should be able to see this menu, but non-content editors should not be able to see this menu at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing PermissionsString to "ManageWeb"... it will hide for all users who doesn't have ManageWeb role... How are you going to categorize "certain users" in your question, if it is by role, you can quickly have a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i know its a bit of a cheat way round, but i used this from codeplex... you can sepecify what users see it through groups http://spribbonvisibility.codeplex.com/

the only issue is it does remove the users name from top right, and leaves no menu there...